# Find PID of the connected Unix Domain Socket

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ipc

I've written simple client server program in python with file socket in Mac OS. I would like to know the process id of the connected client socket from server. I achieved in linux, but I couldn't find any way for Mac OS.

Comment: Assuming you have access to the thread or process that is running the client you can call `os.getpid()` in that thread or process. If you don't you should specify this in your question.

Comment: @Mr.Zeus os.getpid() fetch only the current process id only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this Golang issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27613) implementing the same thing, you can do

```
sock, addr = server.accept()
other_pid = sock.getsockopt(0, 2)
```

where `0` corresponds to `SOL_LOCAL` and `2` to `LOCAL_PEERPID`.

I just tried it out – works fine on my Mac.